# Sectioning the NSMutableArray of dictionaries

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I am having array of dictionaries like below, I need to sectioned below array according to 'create_time' as section-title of UITableView. And load accordingly in to tableview. Please help how to make formatted array having section.

```
 ({
        content = hellow;
        "create_time" = 1436797644;
        "from_id" = 290;
        "from_name" = waterfall;
        "group_id" = "<null>";
        id = 1;
        "send_time" = 1436797644;
        "session_id" = 1436797620;
        "state_id" = 0;
        "to_id" = 289;
        "to_name" = prof2;
        "type_id" = 1;
    } );
```

Here is little stuff about code what i did:

```
arr_CompleteChat=[[DataBaseController getInstance] readChat:userID withFromId:friendID withLimit:20];

 SqlStatementt =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM MessageList where (from_id=%ld and to_id=%ld) OR  (from_id=%ld and to_id=%ld) order by create_time DESC LIMIT %d",(long)[to_id integerValue],(long)[from_id integerValue],mode,(long)[from_id integerValue],(long)[to_id integerValue],limit];
```

and about table view loading:

```
         -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
         {
          return [arr_CompleteChat count];
         }
         -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
        {
           return 1;
         }

      -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView      
cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
 if([[[arr_CompleteChat objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"from_id"] isEqualToString:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"MY_ID"]])
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
    SendMsgBubbleCell *temp=(SendMsgBubbleCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (temp == nil)
    {
        temp = [[SendMsgBubbleCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SendMsgBubbleCell" owner:temp options:nil];
        [temp loaditemwithMessageArray:[arr_CompleteChat objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        temp=[topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    }


    return temp;
}
else
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
    ReciveMsgBubbleCell *temp=(ReciveMsgBubbleCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (temp == nil)
    {
        temp = [[ReciveMsgBubbleCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ReciveMsgBubbleCell" owner:temp options:nil];
        [temp loaditemwithMessageArray:[arr_CompleteChat objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]  ];
        temp=[topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    return temp;
    }
    }
```

Now i wish to convert the whole arr_completechat in section wise of UItableview. I guess its more than enough code snippet to understand.

Comment: You better give us your relevant code to see what you've done so that it's easier for us to help.

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the array and get the value for the key `create_time`. If a section with that value already exists in your table view, you simply have to add a cell to it. Otherwise you first have to create a new section and then add the cell.

This is almost pseudocode. Once you know the proper methods to use, it's simple to achieve what you want.

Comment: i appreciate your response. Please look at the update in code.